# problem while accessing same object from multiple threads simultaneously using lock_guard

Tags: c++, synchronization, locking, p2p, lock-guard

```
Peer* Subtracker::getPeer(int packetNum, Peer* p, Peer* nearestP)
{
    lock_guard<mutex> guard(this->m);
    double d = DBL_MAX;
    for(auto it:packetToPeersMapping[packetNum])
    {
        double dTemp = sqrt(pow(p->x - it->x, 2) + pow(p->y - (it)->y, 2));
        if(dTemp <= d)
        {
            nearestP = it;
        }
    }
    packetToPeersMapping[packetNum].push_back(p);

    return nearestP;    
}
```

```
void Peer::operate()
{
    // some initial code    

    for(int i=0;i<NUM_PACKETS;i++)
    {
        if(packets.find(i)!=packets.end())
        {
            // Packet already with peer do nothing
            packetTime[i] = {this->ID, 0};
        }
        else
        {
            Peer *peer = nullptr;
            peer = subtracker->getPeer(i, this, peer);

            packets.insert(i);
            packetTime[i] = {peer->ID, expression to calculate time};

        }
    }

    // SOME OTHER CODE
}
```

I am using lock_guard for synchronization among peers accessing the subtrackers. There are some peers and one of those peers is also a subtracker. The job of subtracker `getPeer()` method is to calculate the nearest peer which contains a certain packet which the requesting peer needs. Synchronization is basically needed in `packetToPeersMapping`, which contains the info about the peers having a particular packet. Each peer is a separate thread and has a subtracker assigned to it.

Ideally, if a peer needs a packet, it will call the `getPeer()` method and the nearest peer will be returned. Upon running the code, sometimes even if the current peer does not have the necessary packet, the `getPeer()` method is returning the current peer as the nearest peer having the packet. I think there is something wrong with the way I'm using **lock_guard**

Comment: Unfortunately, because the shown code does not meet the requirements for a [mre], it is unlikely that anyone will be able to tell you anything.

Comment: What happens if two `Peer` instances call `subtracker->getPeer(i, this, peer);` with same value of `i` (if that's possible)?  Can they return the same `Peer *`?  If so, you possibly have a race condition.  Really need to see more code though -- preferably a [mcve].